# Scanning values in C till hit a new-line char, '\n'

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, scanf, getchar

How can I `scanf()` the integer values I enter into an array until I hit enter.

I believe I can use `getchar() != '\n'`.

but how do I loop through the line ?

Suppose my input is `20 21 2 12 2`. I want an array that has all those inputs. 
What given functions could I use in order to scan them all in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are trying to read integers as characters so once read you need to convert it to integers.
2. Read the line to a buffer using `fgets()` then parse the input buffer to get integers.
3. Store the integers to the array.

The code looks like

```
char buf[300];
int a[5],i=0;
fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
char *p = strtok(buf," ");
while(p != NULL)
{
  char *endptr;
  a[i] = strtol(p,&endptr,10);
  if ((*endptr != '\0') && (isspace(*endptr) == 0))
      printf("warning: invalid value detected\n");
  else
      i++;
  p = strtok(NULL," ");
}
```

You can use the alternative `strtol()` instead of `atoi()` to convert string to integer.

PS: Your `buf` should be large enough to hold the whole line. `fgets()` read till newline character.

Comment: Better to use the various white-space of `isspace()` in `strtok()` to be consistent with `isspace(()` rather than just `" "`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `getchar()` you obtain digits one by one, so you need
to store them first in the buffer, and when white space comes,
you convert those digits into a number, and store it into array.

here is the explanation of the code I made for you.

- 1st if statement : if obtained character is a digit, store it in `buf`
- 2nd if statement : if obtained character is a white space or EOL and at least 1 digit is stored in `buf`, convert digits into number and store it in array `a`.
- 3rd if statement : if obtained character is not a digit or a white space or a EOL, warns users.
- 4th if statement : if obtained character is a EOL, end loop.

The code below works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
#define BUFSIZE 50
#define ARRAYSIZE 5
    int i,k,a[ARRAYSIZE];
    char c,buf[BUFSIZE];

    for(i=0,k=0;(i<BUFSIZE)&&(k<ARRAYSIZE);){
        c=getchar();
        if(isdigit(c)){
            buf[i++] = c;
        }else if((i>0) && (c==' ' || c=='\n')){
            buf[i] = '\0';
            a[k++] = atoi(buf);
            i=0;
        }else if(!(c==' ' || c=='\n')){
            printf("warning : invalid value %c is detected\n",c);
            i=0;
        }
        if(c=='\n'){
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("input :");
    for(i=0;i<ARRAYSIZE;i++){
        printf("%d, ",a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```